# Import large .txt MathML expression

Tags: import

I have extremely large .txt file (around 180 MB in the MathML form). This .txt file contains simplified expression in polynomial form and can not be reduced more. After starting the import process, after two days Mathematica 11 is still working. Is there any solution how to speed up it. Ram memory is 10% used all the time.

Large file is uploading long time (few days and nothing) MathML .txt:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ayc1i46bv24823/numerator.txt?dl=0

Small .txt with the same MathML structure is uploading fast (few swconds):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5y4tlk15jqbt49/num.txt?dl=0

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
imp = Import["num.txt"];
eq = ImportString[imp, "Expression"];
```

Comment: Try `"HeldExpression"` or `"InactiveExpression"`. Is it possible that any of the variables in the expression had values assigned to them when `ImportString` was run?  This would cause *Mathematica* to substitute those values into the expression and then calculate to resolve `eq`.  Depending on what they are this could take a while.

Comment: This is very hard to answer without knowing more details on what the file contains.  One suggestion I have is using Streams to do a line by line read/write, as this can be more efficient that attempting to process all 180MB at a time (though of course this depends on the structure of the file)

Comment: Did you export the expression with Mathematica and was it fast to do so?

Comment: This takes less than 10 seconds: `ToExpression[
   ToString@Expand[(1 + x)^20000],
   InputForm,
   HoldComplete
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming`.  The data it produces is ~170 MB.  As Edmund said, try `str = Import["num.txt", "String"]; expr = ToExpression[str, InputForm, HoldComplete];`.  It can't be the parsing that's slow, it must be the evaluation.  Your first `Import` *should* specify the format. Don't leave it to chance.

Comment: I did not write that .txt is in MathML form. Because of that Szabolic's suggestion does not work. I edited the question. Sorry because of forgotten information about .txt notation.

Comment: Then use `Import[..., {"MathML", "HeldExpression"}]`.  Your code may or may not do the same thing because you are relying on automatic format detection.  Whether this is fast or not, I do not know.

Comment: try https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ayc1i46bv24823/numerator.txt?dl=0

Comment: does not work with Import[..., {"MathML", "HeldExpression"}].

Comment: Can you successfully import smaller examples?

Comment: yes, small works fine george2079

Comment: @george2079 please see edited question. Small .txt file with the same structure is working fine. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5y4tlk15jqbt49/num.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Szabolcs expression is not generated in Mathematica

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what to do in that case. The MathML parser is just much slower than the parser for Mathematica expressions.  If you need to transfer expressions from one algebra system to another, perhaps try this: http://www.symbolic-computing.org/science/index.php/The_SCIEnce_Project I have never used it and I do not know if it will be faster or if it will even be useful to you.

Comment: @Szabolcs for information thanks, but if you will have some idea to import the file by parts, any help will be good